# "No such session" / "chrome not reachable" error when running Chrome in parallel in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, parallel-testing

I am getting the issue with running automation tests on Chrome in Jenkins using parallel_test gem (also use with Capybara, selenium - Ruby language). I'm running it in headless mode with Xvfb. However, most of all test scenarios failed due to 'no such session' or 'chrome not reachable' errors.
This is my run command on test job in Jenkins:

```
xvfb-run -a --server-args='-screen 0 1680x1050x24' bundle exec parallel_cucumber features/ -n 4 -o '-t ~@ignore -p jenkins_chrome'
```

This is my register_driver in env.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
         browser: :chrome,
         desired_capabilities: {
             "chromeOptions" => {
                 "args" => %w{ --start-maximized --disable-impl-side-painting --no-sandbox }
             }
         })
  end
```

And this is error message:

```
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.0.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError)
./features/step_definitions/view_a_profile.rb:204:in `/^user has signed in as "([^"]*)"$/'
```

Someone said the errors are due to xvfb, some said due to Chrome can't run in parallel.
Have anyone experienced this issue? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome with chromedriver and xvfb won't run on any
   suse. (probably not related here)

Usually on build servers everything gets executed as root, which
   causes this exact error for me with chrome. (for this I am searching for a workaround myself)